# Better Handling of getting data from server in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad

I need to improve my coding.so i am finding something better.

My problem is i need to fetch the data from server from 10 different url.that url have images 100.

for example i need to hit

`http://192.168.11.222/images/a`
`http://192.168.11.222/images/b`
`http://192.168.11.222/images/c`
`http://192.168.11.222/images/d`
`http://192.168.11.222/images/e`
`http://192.168.11.222/images/f`
`http://192.168.11.222/images/g`
`http://192.168.11.222/images/h`
`http://192.168.11.222/images/i`

so a b c d e are folder on server that contain images.

Currently i am doing this through NSURLConnectionWithTag and then parse the response.and get saved.is there any another better way to handle this? i also need to show progress bar which is also difficult in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I would setup an NSOperationQueue ,with a single operation per URL and set it to, say, three concurrent operations. Then use NSURLConnection's non-asynchronous API to do the download.

For your progress bar, it's probably good enough to update the progress after each individual file is finished, and do two of them at a time (or something). Chances are latency will be more than half the "progress" anyway, so unless you start trying to predict your ping times, a progress bar based on the actual bytes transferred will not be accurate enough to bother (unless these are very big images).

You will need to learn how operation queues and GCD work, but once you've got that sorted it really won't be much code at all, and it will be rock solid.

Basically you want to add a "block" of code to the operation queue for each URL to download, and the queue will figure out how to download each one, and then when each individual block of code is  finished it executes another block on the main thread (`dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ ... })`) to update the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to write network related code in your app, I recommend take a look at [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/), it's a wrap of network API iOS already provided with much less hassle.